# Touch versus trace typing

Tags: input, keyboard

Do you think trace typing (as provided by apps like Swype and SwiftKey, and now integrated in many smartphones UI) can replace touch typing? Any data on typing speed with this new input method?

I was thinking that it would be interesting to have a flat PC keyboard on which you can combine both typing methods for even faster typing speeds?!!

Comment: If there are studies out there I wouldn't necessarily extrapolate them to full-size keyboard usage. A big desktop keyboard sized touch pad may not be suitable for such usage.

Comment: True, but it doesn't have to be direct extrapolation. Maybe a new typing method can evolve in which you combine touch with tracing, saving the time of finger lifts between keystrokes.

Comment: maybe, and it's certainly something worth considering. Keyboards have been around for so long without much innovation, unlike most other interaction interface systems. Whether swype style interactions can help move the technology and experiences onwards is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you asked for data, the following answer on skeptics stackexchange has good references to two studies which conclude that there is no net performance advantage to using swype over conventional touch keyboards:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/26471

[image]

The two studies are here:

- http://m.pro.sagepub.com/content/56/1/1591.full.pdf
- http://www.resna.org/sites/default/files/legacy/conference/proceedings/2012/PDFs/Scientific/ComputersandCommunication/Swypevrs.ConventionalOn-ScreenKeyboards.pdf

There have been some attempts to create hybrid swipe/touch keyboards. One notable effort which grabbed headlines last year (circa Jan 2014) was hipjot:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTecUnSgHXw

I don't think a full size swype keyboard would be successful. You can see for yourself using a low-fidelity prototype: just print out a full size keyboard on a sheet of paper (eg [this](http://maneeshchiba.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Keyboard-example.png)) 
 and try swiping across it. You will see that the distance your fingers need to travel is much greater, which renders the keyboard much slower than the standard touch typing interaction.

---

Btw it's interesting that the studies show a bias in perception towards swype. It's an interesting UX point to ponder. I believe the swipe interface provides a greater illusion of speed for users because there is tactile feedback as the user slides between keys, even though performance yields similar results and air provides less resistance than glass when moving between keys.

Comment: Interesting.  Subjectively, it seems much better.

Comment: @dan1111 agreed. I added a footnote on that because it's interesting to ponder what drives the perception-reality gap

Comment: I used gesture typing almost exclusively on my Nexus 7. (Tapping out non-standard words.) I miss it now that I've got an iPhone. And yes, my perception was that it was faster. Maybe it was just easier.

Comment: @tohster, there is a perception-reality gap, but there also can be a research-reality gap.  So I'm not 100% convinced yet.  The most recent version of Swype I had was terrible at guessing words.  I downloaded Google keyboard and did much better with that.  So, the technology could be beneficial, but not a particular implementation of it.

Comment: @dan1111 that might certainly be the case. The technology has evolved. It's hard to conjecture an answer on this unfortunately!

Comment: Interesting read in the links:   
"However, our subjects all preferred using Swype over ScreenDoors [the on-screen keyboard]"

Comment: I notice, though, that the typing rates for either are in the 10-14 WPM range, which is perhaps a third of what 'average' computer users do on a normal keyboard, and less than 20% of the rate a good typist can acheive.

Comment: Good to know that some people are interested in researching the subject. However, I'm not sure if the study is any evidence. For once, they turned off the prediction feature, which renders tracing useless. Also, the comparison does not give clear indication of the level of expertise with the system. Even touch typing can be very slow for novice users.

Comment: The study is highly suspect. The error rates were low, but it took 6 seconds to trace a word. The subjects were probably hunt-and-peck typists who spent most of their time finding the letters irrespective of input method.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I don't think that is a reasonable opinion. The study does a good job describing what the sample set was, what tests were conducted, and what the environment was.  The aim of the study was to assess the **relative** and not the absolute performance of swipe versus tap, so it's unreasonable to expect that the charts would be indicative of anything other than relative performance of the two keyboards for the sample.  The WPM denominator may have included common factored reading time for the questions, etc, normalized out between the two keyboards.

Comment: @tohster The study does a bad job of describing the test subjects. You are suggesting that we ignore the unusually low WPM numbers. (I'll remind you that the units are explicitly WPM, not some normalized abstract baseline.) I see no reason that we should ignore them. They are suspect and unexplained, and the make the entire study suspect. Typical WPM for smartphones is [at least 20](http://www.informationweek.com/mobile/mobile-devices/smartphone-keyboards-vs-your-productivity/d/d-id/1102283?) and is [higher for tablets](http://www.educate1to1.org/ipad-vs-pc-typing-speeds-students/).

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky You certainly cannot compare WPM within the confines of an academic study with WPM for general mobile users.  That is like saying a Porsche is not a performance car because crash test drivers averaged only 35mph on a testing circuit and most people drive at 60mph on the highway.

Comment: Btw, the second study uses a "head mouse" (a camera that watches head movement), not a touchscreen. Moreover, the test subjects had little or no experience using a head mouse. This is what explains the 7 WPM speed in that study.

Comment: Why can't I? I'll give a better analogy. Test subjects assessed the handling of several cars, but while driving at 11-13 MPH they found that the Porsche was identical to every other car with power steering. P.S. I do not know what a crash test driver is, but it sounds painful.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky I think we can simply agree to disagree here, since I have no inclination to explain the concept of relative measurement in experiment design that is basic to academic research.

Comment: The P-value for speed difference is $p=0.11$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I misread. The p-value for the speed difference is not reported (just "not significant"). For comparison, elsewhere in the pape p=0.11 and p=0.13 are considered significant.

Answer (score 5):

The [wikipedia page on Swipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swype) states:

> The creators of Swype predict that users will achieve over 50 words
>   per minute, with the chief technical officer (CTO) and founder Cliff
>   Kushler claiming to have reached 55 words per minute.

This appears to be based on company claims rather than actual evidence.  However, even if we take these claims at face value, this speed is [at the low end of what a professional typist can do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_per_minute):

> An average professional typist types usually in speeds of 50 to 80
>   wpm, while some positions can require 80 to 95 (usually the minimum
>   required for dispatch positions and other time-sensitive typing jobs),
>   and some advanced typists work at speeds above 120 wpm.

Several people have managed to type more than 200 WPM.

And this is comparing a "dumb" keyboard to technology that enhances accuracy with software.  Keyboard entry can be even faster when combined with similar software technology.  For example, [some stenotypists can type over 300 WPM and >200 WPM is the norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stenotype).

It is possible that trace typing speeds will be competitive for non-experts.  However, I doubt they could ever compete with keyboards for professional typing.  The action of moving one's finger across the screen requires greater precision than typing with keys, and I think this is a physical limitation that won't be overcome.

The technology is a great step forward for text entry on a phone, though (*update: maybe [in my subjective opinion only](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/74633/31143)*).

Comment: Are you really comparing swiping on a phone with touch-typing on a keyboard?

Comment: @PieterB, yes.  That is how I interpreted the question...maybe wrongly.  After re-reading it, I'm still not sure.  It does refer to a computer keyboard, and this is traditionally what "touch typing" means.

Comment: For clarity, pushing letters on a touch screen is not touch typing.   Touch typing is what I'm doing right now.  I'm typing on a keyboard without looking at the keys.

Answer (score 4):

Trace typing isn't new. It was invented over a decade ago and was known as [IBM SHARK](http://www.shuminzhai.com/ShapeWriterHistory.htm).

There are several crucial differences between current smartphone keyboards and the original concept:

- SHARK used a non-standard keyboard layout called [ATOMIK](http://www.shuminzhai.com/ATOMIK.htm). The purpose of this layout was to greatly reduce the number of mis-recognitions by making the shapes of common words more distinct. For example, "is" and "its" were traced very differently, unlike when using the QWERTY layout.
- SHARK was meant to be used with a stylus, which is arguably more dexterous to manipulate than a finger and lends itself to not being lifting.

The ultimate point was not to let the user connect letters without lifting a finger, but to let the user write in "shorthand." Ie, to not think about letters at all but let the word's shape be memorized and written as a sort of hieroglyph.

[Shorthand (hieroglyph-like) handwriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teeline_Shorthand) is known to be a very fast alternative to standard handwriting and typing, allowing speeds in excess of 100 WPM, so the potential for a computerized version is large.

I believe that by embracing SHARK's two advantages, using powerful algorithms, and anticipating sufficient practice on a user's part (which, of course, is unthinkable these days) can lead to significant typing speed gains over a tap touchscreen keyboard. However, I'm not sure if it would be faster than a full physical keyboard, especially when used for non-lexical input.

Comment: Please share where you are getting the 100WPM from.  The co-inventor of SHARK, Per-Ola Kristensson, estimated expert-level performance at 45WPM.  This was arrived at with a good degree of both empirical and theoretical study in an academic research paper: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.67.5793&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @tohster >100 WPM is in reference to *shorthand handwriting*.

Answer (score -1):

Trace typing cannot replace key-based entry methods because it does not have the capabilities that key-based methods do.

In order to provide a smooth input experience, trace typing is generous in converting your swipes to words rather than precise. Thus it represents a "best guess" as to what you intended to type based on your action and on the words it thinks you may be trying to enter. This is usually beneficial but if I want to enter a word that is not in the dictionary it suddenly becomes almost entirely useless. To enter new words you need to switch to key-by-key entry.